# PHP & MySQL delete all comments related to an article question

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have 20 comments that are related to article_id `76` will I have to count all the article ids that have an article_id `76` and then run a foreach loop for all the comments related to article 76 or can I delete all the comments related to that article using a query?

```
SELECT article_id FROM articles_comments WHERE article_id = 76
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM articles_comments WHERE article_id = 76;
```

Comment: will this delete all article rows with an article id of 76 or will I have to run a foreach loop?

Comment: @aatteot It will delete all of them

Comment: @fredley: Thanks!
@aatteot: It will delete all records having the field article_id set to the given value.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM articles_comments WHERE article_id = 76`

Comment: will this delete all article rows with an article id of 76 or will I have to run a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just one operation:

```
 delete from article_comments where article_id = 76
```

Comment: will this delete all article rows with an article id of 76 or will I have to run a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

No need for any looping.

This one query will delete all the comments related to `article_id` `76`

```
DELETE FROM articles_comments 
WHERE article_id = 76;
```

Comment: will this delete all article rows with an article id of 76 or will I have to run a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, this will delete **all** rows from `article_comments` which have `article_id` equal to `76`